# Is it possible to return multiple entity collections from a server side method in Wakanda?

Tags: javascript, wakanda

I have the following server side method:

```
model.Public.someMethod = function(){
  var collections = {};
  collections.collection1 = ds.SomeClass.query("ID > 10");
  collections.collection2 = ds.SomeOtherClass.query("ID > 10");
  return collections;
}
model.Public.someMethod.scope = "public";
```

When I call this function from the browser, I do not get an error, or a a response. I have tested complex objects, they return fine, I've returned a single entity collection (collections.collection1) which works fine as well.

Am I able to return a group of entity collections in one request? Thanks.

To be more clear, I am using WAF on the front end and the "onSuccess" parameter.

Comment: I was able to return an object containing two collection (the same way as you tried to) with and without the onSuccess function. 

Did you tried to debug serverSide to make sure sure the object "collections" is containing the 2 collections before the server return it?

And in the onSuccess function what do you get in event.result object ?

Answer (score 1):

Doing a similar method on a dataClass, and calling it directly with REST API shows that the returned object only contains arrays of entities, and not entity collections.

Example:

```
model.Employee.methods.employeesBySalary = function() {
    var high = ds.Employee.query("salary > 100000");
    var low = ds.Employee.query("salary < 40000");
    return {high: high, low: low};
};
```

Result:

```
{
  "result": {
    "high": [
      {
        "__KEY": "56033",
        "__STAMP": 111,
        "ID": 56033,
        "lastName": "BUDADO",
        "firstName": "TIMOTHY",
        "salary": 149541
      },
      ...
    ],
    "low": [
      {
        "__KEY": "55938",
        "__STAMP": 111,
        "ID": 55938,
        "lastName": "RATUSA",
        "firstName": "IRWIN"
      },
      ...
    ]
  }
}
```

So, you actually can't return collections *stricto sensu*, but you can return their content, without the collection features like paging, etc.